# Empty grouping Jqgrid - group with no items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to have grids in jqgrid with groupings that have no items (0 items) ?

For example I want to add a test4 group that have no items, and can work with pagination and sorting.

```js
var mydata = [
  {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
  {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"21.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"12",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"13",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"15",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"16",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"18",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"19",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"21",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"22",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"23",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"24",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"25",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"26",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
  {id:"27",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
  {id:"28",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
  {id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
 ];
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
 data: mydata,
 datatype: "local",
 height: 'auto',
 rowNum: 30,
 rowList: [10,20,30],
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
     {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
     {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, editable:true},
     {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number", editable:true},
     {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", editable:true},  
     {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},  
     {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}  
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'name',
    grouping:true,
    groupingView : {
     groupField : ['name'],
     groupColumnShow : [false],
     groupText : ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>']
    },
    caption: "Configure group header row"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. jqGrid sorts the data items by `groupingView.groupField` as the first sorting filed and by `sortname` as the second sorting name. The results of sorting will be displayed in the grid. The only difference to the standard grid in inserting of additional rows with grouping headers before **the data**. The grouping headers contains "+" icon to hide/show the data rows of the group.

You can of cause add any custom row in the middle of the grid, which looks like grouping header, but you have to manage all things yourself. For example, you have to decide on which page and under which place the custom row need be inserted.